# Write to hidden files in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io, hidden

I have a problem with my hidden files in Java. I would like to write to a hidden txt file but it always says "access denied".
My suggestion would be to make the file visible, write into it and then make it hidden again.
But how can i make a hidden file visible?

Comment: Hidden/writable are orthogonal: just because a file is hidden doesn't mean it's read-only. Also: which OS are you talking about? What files?

Comment: Are you certain that your write is rejected because the file is hidden? Couldn't it be that the user you are running as has no access to the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875280/modify-a-hidden-file-in-java

Comment: There used to be old Delphi (Borland Pascal?) runtimes which ignored hidden files. I know of no Java variant which does this just as wrong. On windows, use attrib so look at and manipulate a file´s file attributes, yet unhiding the file probably won´t help in this case.

Comment: It would be helpful to know your target platform and your Java version, and also to see how you try the open (sho uz da codez...).

Comment: Just encountered the same problem. I it seems that at least Windows JVM 1.7, 64bit indeed considers hidden files to be read only. Which is plain wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I previously said: <strike>The problem is not that the file is hidden.  The problem is that your program doesn't have write access for the file.  Making it "unhidden" is unlikely to help.</strike>

It seems that it is more complicated than that for Windows.  Certainly it is worth trying to "unhide" the file before modifying it.

Anyway, if you are using Java 7, the way to read and write Windows-specific file attributes is to use the [`java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) API, and specifically the [`getFileAttributeView(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getFileAttributeView%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29) method.  For older versions you will either need to use an external utility (see @Achintya Jha's Answer) or use a JNI / JNA wrapper to call a Windows native API.

If you are using Linux, change Windows-specific to POSIX and/or Linux specific.  (Note that a lot of this stuff to do with file attributes and permissions is intrinsically OS specific.)

Finally, if the problem is that the program doesn't have write access to the file, there is a fair chance that there is nothing that *it* can do to get write access.

Comment: It was said: on any OS. How would WIndows specific file attributes held there?

Comment: while i didnt set my file to hidden it worked perfectly to write into it
in which way should i use the method?