# Download something to appdata

Tags: java

I have a java program that downloads a file(a jar file).
I want to get this downloaded in the users appdata folder.
How would I do this?
I tried this:

```
private static String myClient = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/AppData/Roaming";
```

But this says:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ruud\AppData\Roaming (Access denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at Main.main(Main.java:108)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: If I understand the Exception correctly, your program is not allowed to write in the AppData/Roaming folder. You'll need to give the program the write rights to that folder.

Comment: Try to write into `System.getenv("appdata")` instead

Comment: Burkhard I knew that already, but ty for the response.
@msrd0 I did that now. it looks like this:
`private static String myClient = System.getenv("appdata");`

Comment: I got it fixed, it was because I had to change something in the code. How can I mark this solved?

Answer (score 2):

1. This can happen due to Hidden attribute on windows folder **'AppData'**
   try with clearing hidden attribute of the **'AppData'** folder.

   check [Modify a hidden file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875280/modify-a-hidden-file-in-java) to address hidden problems like this.

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -H myFile.txt");` to clear hidden attribute.

2. This can happen due to Permission problems for folder. try with assigning folder write access to users.

Comment: How would I use this for the appdata folder?
something like this?
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -H " + System.getenv("appdata")) `

Answer (score 0):

Ensure tha the `AppData` target folder exists running:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/AppData/").mkdir()
```